# Namespace with only one word ends in syntax error

Tags: thrift

In a thrift definition file (*.thrift) I want to use the namespace 'service'. But it causes an syntax error with the message 'last token was "service"'. Is this against any syntactical regulations? When I try the namespace "com.service" its all fine.

Comment: Ah. I guess it could be the fact that 'service' is a reserved word

Comment: Did you know? Providing some examples can dramatically increase the answer rate! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

> Ah. I guess it could be the fact that 'service' is a reserved word

```
namespace * service
```

Indeed, it looks that way, especially because

```
namespace * xervice
```

works. I agree that the wording of the error message is probably a bit misleading, but technically absolutely correct: `service` is the keyword to start a service definition.